# adding values returned in foreach php

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php if($grades->subcompid==$subcomp->id && $grades->compid=='1' && $grades->termid=='1' && $grades->recordid==$recid && $grades->studentid==$student->studentid){
   echo $grades->grade;
?>
```

I wish to echo the values 20, 25, 14, 12, and 45-- and the above code does so.

The problem is I want to add those values to get 116 so I did this:

```
$midtermg = 0;    
<?php if($grades->subcompid==$subcomp->id && $grades->compid=='1' && $grades->termid=='1' && $grades->recordid==$recid && $grades->studentid==$student->studentid){
    $midtermg = $midtermg + $grades->grade;
    echo $midtermg;
}
```

However it returned the values '20 45 59 71 116'. It added the value to next value and echoed each. I tried doing `echo end($midtermg);` but it says it is not an array so it doesnt work. What to do if I just want the 116 be echoed?

*the if statement returns the correct values so please dont mind it

Comment: Show the input data.

Comment: echo your variable outside the main loop

Comment: put $midtermg = 0;  and echo $midtermg; outside the loop if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.Every time you are printing value inside `if`.Just sum values inside loop.And print after `if` condition.

```
<?php
$midtermg = 0;    
 if($grades->subcompid==$subcomp->id && $grades->compid=='1' && $grades->termid=='1' && $grades->recordid==$recid && $grades->studentid==$student->studentid){
    $midtermg = $midtermg + $grades->grade;

} 

echo $midtermg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an array and push conditional satisfied values into array, then you can play with this array.

```
<?php
$midtermg = 0;
$a_results= array();    
if($grades->subcompid==$subcomp->id && $grades->compid=='1' && $grades->termid=='1' && $grades->recordid==$recid && $grades->studentid==$student->studentid){
    // $midtermg = $midtermg + $grades->grade;
    array_push($a_results, $grades->grade);
} 
echo array_sum($a_results);
```